# How to import a JSON-style table [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']] into Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, json

Let's say I have copied a JSON-style string like this:

```
 [['a', 'what\'s up'], ['c', 'd']]
```

into the clipboard (for example copied from my browser Dev Console, after some JS code).

**How can I easily paste this into a Google Sheet, directly into cells (split by columns / rows)?**

Answer (score 0):

Create a new script:

```
/**
 * Evaluates JS code.
 *
 * @param {code} code The code to evaluate.
 * @return The result from evaluating the code.
 * @customfunction
 */
function RUNJS(code) {
  return eval(code); 
}
```

than paste your JS into cell A2 (for example) and put this formula in A3:

```
=RUNJS(A2)
```

the result will be:

[image: JS]

Comment: Where do you create this script, and how to link it with this particular spreadsheet? Also, if `RUNJS` just does `eval`, isn't it possible to just execute `eval` in Google Sheets directly?

Comment: paste the script into: Extensions-->Apps Script -->Files ( add a file )--> Script This script will work only in the sheet where it was created. There is no Eval () function in google sheet but if you prefer you could name this EVAL.

Comment: Would `JSON.parse()` be safer than `eval()`?

Comment: I don't know... but JSON do not use single quotations mark... you could try ... no danger